# Switching turns in a player game

Tags: c#

I have a turn based player game code in c# that needs to switch players after 3 rolls of a dice by player 1. Player 2 rolls 3 times and it passes on to the other player.

I have a code below, but would like to understand lets say turn 1,2,3 is for player 1 and 4,5,6 is for player 2 and the next ascending three numbers is back to player 1. All this is executed when a button is clicked to roll.

Right now, after the 6th click to roll, it remains at player 2. Would like the program to switch back to player one after the 6th roll so that he can roll 3 times again.

Looking for something like a loop back to player 1 after player 2. Like while loop.

Thanks in advance.

```
    private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (turn <= 2 && turn % 3 == 0)
        {
            tbxOutput.AppendText("Player 1 Turn" + Environment.NewLine);
            playerOne = seqOfFive() + seqOfFour() + seqOfThree() + fiveOfKind() + fourOfKind() + threeOfKind();
        }

        if (turn >= 3 && turn % 3 == 0)
        {
            tbxOutput.AppendText("Player 2 Turn" + Environment.NewLine);
            playerTwo = seqOfFive() + seqOfFour() + seqOfThree() + fiveOfKind() + fourOfKind() + threeOfKind();
        }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: are you looking for an algorithm that can calculate the turn numbers for each player given the number of turns and the number of players?

Comment: I would like to switch players after 3 turns and not just end with displaying player 2 after the 6 and onwards turn. Yes probably a simple algorithm.

Comment: you can use turn%6>2 player 2 otherwise player 1, just increase the turn

Comment: Are you looking for Modulo? A way to tell that every N turn we switch player? Or a counter. [Modulo documentation`%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)

Answer (score 2):

For two player, you can Simply have a boolean. Every 3 turn, you invert it's value

```
var turn = 0;

var player1Turns = true;
while (true)
{
    turn++;
    if (player1Turns)
    {
        //player One play
    }
    else
    {
        //player Two play
    }

    if (turn % 3 == 0)
    {
        player1Turns = !player1Turns;
    }
}
```

Let's go a step further and try to implement it for N players.
I will add rules to the game:
 - N players
 - Roll a dice 6, 3 times in a row. and add it to his score.
 - Till one of them reach 21.
 - Score exceding the target value will be reset to 0
   Exemple: 20+6= 0;

Those simple rules where add so we have to store a Player score and a game mechanic:

```
//  Rulez 
var consecutiveTrun = 3;
var targetValue = 21;
int numberOfPlayers = 5;
int Random6Dice() => rnd.Next(1, 7);

//initilise the array that store players score 
var playerScores = new int[numberOfPlayers]; 
var turn = 0;
var currentPlayer = 0;

while (!playerScores.Contains(targetValue))
{
    turn++;

    Console.Write($"\n> Trun n°{turn,4}\t");

    var playerRoll = Random6Dice(); // Player roll the dice.
    Console.Write($"Player #{currentPlayer + 1,2}\t " +
        $"has {playerScores[currentPlayer],2} " +
        $"and roll: {playerRoll}\t");

    var rawScore = playerScores[currentPlayer] + playerRoll;
    playerScores[currentPlayer] = ( rawScore > targetValue) ? 0 : rawScore;
    Console.Write($"Total Score = { playerScores[currentPlayer],2}");

    if (turn % consecutiveTrun == 0)
    {
        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % numberOfPlayers;
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Spoon feeding: fixed your code in 5 copy past

```
// Get Turn outside of the function the form has to know the number of turn and not restart it at each click
var turn = 0;   

private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    turn++;
    if (player1Turns)
    {
        tbxOutput.AppendText("Player 1 Turn" + Environment.NewLine);
        playerOne = seqOfFive() + seqOfFour() + seqOfThree() + fiveOfKind() + fourOfKind() + threeOfKind();
    }
    else
    {
        tbxOutput.AppendText("Player 2 Turn" + Environment.NewLine);
        playerTwo = seqOfFive() + seqOfFour() + seqOfThree() + fiveOfKind() + fourOfKind() + threeOfKind();
    }

    if (turn % 3 == 0)
    {
        player1Turns = !player1Turns;
    }

}
```

Comment: @MongZhu, bool is just 0 or 1. We have no player class or result or anything to not make "3player" or an array of play more that imaginary code. I would say in in this case. We store the index of the current player in the array. We add 1 to this variable every 3 truns. We Don't forget to modulo  the result to restart from 0 or implement a restart with a simple test.

Comment: But yeah I can easly make a scalable solution.

Comment: Thanks, how do I invert the value to be Player 1 after Player 2 has rolled 3 times? A simple solution would do if you know.

Comment: @Ralph, I don't understand the question.. PlayerOne is already playing after player Two. I copy past the code changed playercount to 2 and press play https://dotnetfiddle.net/RMV5hR !

Comment: The part of the code doing it is `if (turn % consecutiveTrun == 0) currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % numberOfPlayers;` . 
That literraly translate by: If the turn is a multiple of the number of consecutive turn. The current player increase by one. If the result of this operation is equals to the number of player, reset to 0.

Comment: The first code block is more explicite ,Using a bool. The value of the bool is "inverted" every time the turn is a multiple of 3. `if (turn % 3 == 0) player1Turns = !player1Turns;`. The char `!` is the negation operator for a bool ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/logical-negation-operator)).

Comment: Thanks but I just need something simpler to understand cause Im given a task with some rules I have to follow to.

Comment: @Ralph, Use the 1rst code block an the comment starting with "The first code block is more explicite". If it's not simple enought I guess you princess will be in an other castle. As I will not be able to simplify more. Or to explain better. I also failed to see how the "rules _you_ have to follow to" influence your understanding of 3 lines of codes.

Comment: I doubt a bit when you had to leave a comment that was a summary of your question. I asked myself if i had past the answer on the wrong question.

Comment: Even with your updated question I failed to see how it cannot be solved with copy pasting my Irst block into your code.

Comment: Updated answer at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this, although you don't say when the loop should end:

```
var turn = 0;
while (!endCondition)
{
    if (turn <= 2)
    {
        tbxOutput.AppendText("Player 1 Turn" + Environment.NewLine);
        playerOne = seqOfFive() + seqOfFour() + seqOfThree() + fiveOfKind() + fourOfKind() + threeOfKind();
    }

    else if (turn > 2)
    {
        tbxOutput.AppendText("Player 2 Turn" + Environment.NewLine);
        playerTwo = seqOfFive() + seqOfFour() + seqOfThree() + fiveOfKind() + fourOfKind() + threeOfKind();
    }

    turn++;

    if (turn >= 6) turn = 0;
}
```

There are a few other ways to do it, but this is closest to what you have.

Comment: Thanks for this portion of code. The players set a target score to reach in this program, if the target score is reached, the game ends. A bigger target score would mean the turns will be longer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do things in a different way. Think of it this way : you have an unlimited number of turns, let's say. All you need to know is whose turn is it and keep track of that.

I have something similar in a game I built so i can show some code from there:

```
public int TurnCount { get; private set; } //this keeps track of turns
```

main game loop:

```
  while (combatContinues)
            {
                combatContinues = this.Act();
            }
```

inside the *Act* method I do what I need

and this calls another method called *ContinueCombat*

this method increments the turn count, switches sides and does everything else needed:

```
 private void ContinueCombat()
        {
            this.TurnCount++;
            this.SwitchSides();
            this.ActivateFirstAliveActor();
        }
```

in your case it would roll the dice and do whatever you need.

A full example and a working project can be seen here:

https://github.com/guardinfo-spam/rpg-engine

the class where i took the samples from is here :

https://github.com/guardinfo-spam/rpg-engine/blob/master/RpgGamePcl/Combat/CombatScene.cs

Comment: Don't forget the attribution that you are the author of this GitHub to avoid the spam flag.

Comment: I would have thought that this line would kinda be enough : "I have something similar in a game I built ....."

Answer (score 0):

Try this for N players and turns

```
int numOfPlayers = 3, numOfTurns  = 3, currentTurn = 0, currentPlayer, currentPlayerTurn;

while(true)
{
    currentPlayerTurn = currentTurn % numOfTurns;
    currentPlayer = (currentTurn / numOfTurns) % numOfPlayers;

    //toDo

    Console.Write($"Player {currentPlayer + 1}: Turn {currentPlayerTurn + 1} of {numOfTurns}");
    currentTurn ++;
}
```